# Mysql, php query WHERE statement, recordset expire in +1 day of post date?

Tags: mysql, date-manipulation

I basically have a simple calendar I set up. As of now, it shows "future" events. And then the event expires that day... I would love to find a WHERE statement that I can use to have that "event" stay up for 1 day past the "post_date"

(so if I post it as Nov. 15th,) The event would show: **Name of event - Nov. 15th**

And It would stay active until +1 day from post_date? (Nov. 16th would be the expire date)

Here is what I have so far:

```
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) >= DATE(NOW())
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the data type of the `date` and/or `post_date` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE post_date > DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

and if you really want to keep your `post_date`s in UNIX timestamps:

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date) > DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Great! They both work great! Is there a reason I should use :

Comment: WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date)+INTERVAL 1 DAY > DATE(NOW())

Comment: See to it that the expression on that side of the operator that contains the field is not too complicated, otherwise no index is used. I edited my example to make that clear. (Although a simple "+" is optimized away.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your where statement to:

```
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY >= CURDATE();
```

Also a good idea to to use real SQL dates instead of UNIX timestamps. There are functions to do calculations on them.

Comment: This works perfect too!! Is there a big difference between the two answers??

Comment: Not a big difference. Mine compares it based explicitly on the date and ignores the time. @AndreKR's version explicitly uses the date portion of 'NOW' (I used CURDATE which returns the date only). The time portion of FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP is effectively ignored anyway.

Comment: WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(post_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY >= CURDATE() which is a combination of the two, would likely be ever so slightly faster.

Comment: In such a comparison that switches over at midnight, one of both operands has to be a date. The other one can be a time.